# scratchsessionsidの取得はどうすればいいですか？

Tags: cookie

拡張機能を作っていてアカウント関連の部分を現在作成しているのですが、
サイトにログインするためにクッキーを使用しようとしたところ、何故かcookieが取得できませんでした。
scratchsessionsidというcookieを取得したいです。
document.cookie
js-cookie
等の色々な調べて出てきた方法を試してみたが、駄目でした。
言語は拡張機能にした時に動くなら何でもいいので実現したいです。
↓はcookieeditorで見た取得したいcookieです
[image: これはcookieeditorで見た取得したいcookieです]

https://teratail.com/questions/3v6rm3cd3g5tyk でも同様を質問を行っています。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/3v6rm3cd3g5tyk) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ありがとうございます